# what is difference between object and map object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
let m = new Map();

let obj = {};

let keyString = 'a string';
let keyObj = {};
let keyFunc = function() {};

obj[keyObj] = 'object inside object as keys!';
obj[keyFunc] = function() {}


m.set(keyObj, 'object');
m.set(keyFunc, 'function');


console.log(typeof obj[keyObj]); // type = string
console.log(typeof obj[keyFunc]); // type = function 
console.log(typeof m.get(keyObj)); // type = string 
console.log(typeof m.get(keyFunc)); // type = string 
console.log(m.get(keyObj)) //  object
console.log(m.get(keyFunc)) //  function
```

Then what is difference between map and object?
map also converts the keys type to string.

Comment: "*map also converts the keys type to string.*" it DOESN'T! It explicitly keeps their types by design.

Comment: `typeof m.get(keyObj)` returns the value for the key. It is same as `typeof "object"`.

Comment: [Showcasing preserved key types](https://jsbin.com/jebojusuwa/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Map is a data structure which helps in storing the data in the form of pairs. The pair consists of a unique key and a value mapped to the key. It helps prevent duplicity.

Object follows the same concept as that of map i.e. using key-value pair for storing data. But there are slight differences which makes map a better performer in certain situations.

Few basic differences are as follows:

- In Object, the data-type of the key-field is restricted to integer,
  strings, and symbols. Whereas in Map, the key-field can be of any
  data-type (integer, an array, even an object!)
- In the Map, the original order of elements is preserved. This is not
  true in case of objects.
- The Map is an instance of an object but the vice-versa is not true.

Comment: "*In Object, the data-type of the key-field is restricted to integer, strings, and symbols.*" - it's only strings and symbols. You cannot have a number as a key, it gets converted. In few situations "numeric" keys are treated differently but those are still *strings* that contain a non-negative integer.